Expected value for number of dice rolled & rounds played
Game rules

7 players * 5 dice each (regular 6 sided fair dice)
Every round 1 player (assume randomly) will lose 1 die
A player who loses all dice cannot continue to the next round
Final Results will be ranked from 1st to 7th place

For the purpose of this exercice, we can simplify calculations by assuming an equal probability of losing a die across all players.
Round n (1 to max of 35 rounds)

Everyone rolls the dice they have left
One player loses a dice
Next round starts (or game ends if no more players)

Assumptions
(Correct me if i'm wrong)
The minimum rolls any player can have is given by:
5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 15 rolls
This assumes a player lost 1 dice from Round 1 to Round 5

The maximum rolls any player can have is given by:
5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 + (35 - 5 end rounds) * 5 = 165
This assumes a player kept 5 dice for 30 rounds, then lost 1 dice per round in the last 5 rounds

Problem
For any given player, I want to calculate:
1. What is the expected value for # of their dice that were rolled in total?
2. What is the expected value for # of rounds played?
Bonus: How does the distribution of dices rolled vs rounds played look like?
Example
Player ThaBomb starts with 5 dice
Round 1: +5
Round 2: +5 (loses 1 dice)
Round 3: +4
Round ...
Round 26: +1 (loses last die)
Round 27: +0
total = ??

My approach to the solution
Assuming the distribution of dice rolled is pretty symmetric, can we calculate it as an average?
This would give us:
expected total rolls = (min + max) / 2 = (15 + 165)/2 = 90

This is a variant of Banach's Matchbox problem.  That problem has two "players", you want more than two.  Similar techniques should work here.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@msantama You lose 1 dice per round at most, so even if you lose in the first 5 rounds, you would have already rolled 15 dice (5 in the 1st round, 4 in the 2nd, etc...)

here is a duplicate which considers Banach's problem for multiple matchboxes.

Thanks @lulu that seems the closest so far to the problem i'm trying to solve

Does this answer your question? Generalizing Banach's matchbox problem to multiple matchboxes

@EricSnyder it does not exactly, or maybe I couldn't figure out how to calculate the results I needed.
I will update the post with what formulas I was able to come up with myself

This is a partial solution I am accepting for now until proven wrong.
Step-by-Step Solution to Calculate the Expected Rolls
Problem Statement:
Calculate the expected sum of rolled dice for a player given:

$N = 7$ players.
Each player starts with $D = 5$ dice.
Each round, there is a $\frac{1}{7}$ probability of losing a die.
Calculate the expected number of dice rolls per player per game.

Step-by-Step Solution:

Define the Variables:

$D = 5$: Initial number of dice per player.
$N = 7$: Number of players.
$p = \frac{1}{7}$: Probability of losing a die each round.


Expected Number of Rounds to Lose One Die:
The expected number of rounds to lose one die is:
$
   E(\text{Rounds to lose one die}) = \frac{1}{p} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{7}} = 7
   $

Expected Number of Rounds to Lose All Dice:
The player has 5 dice to lose. The expected number of rounds to lose all dice is:
$
   E(\text{Total Rounds}) = D \times E(\text{Rounds to lose one die}) = 5 \times 7 = 35
   $

Expected Number of Dice Rolls per Round:
The expected number of dice rolls in each round decreases as the player loses dice. The expected number of dice the player has in round $r$ is:
$
   E[D_r] = D - (r-1) \times p
   $
Given $p = \frac{1}{7}$:
$
   E[D_r] = 5 - \frac{r-1}{7}
   $

Expected Total Rolls:
To find the expected total rolls, we sum the expected number of dice rolled in each round until the player loses all dice. This involves summing over the expected rounds (35 rounds):
$
   E(\text{Total Rolls}) = \sum_{i=1}^{E(\text{Total Rounds})} E[D_i]
   $
$
   E(\text{Total Rolls}) = \sum_{i=1}^{35} \left( 5 - \frac{i-1}{7} \right)
   $

Simplify the Sum:
The sum can be broken into two parts: a constant term and a linear term.
$
   E(\text{Total Rolls}) = \sum_{i=1}^{35} 5 - \sum_{i=1}^{35} \frac{i-1}{7}
   $
The first part is straightforward:
$
   \sum_{i=1}^{35} 5 = 5 \times 35 = 175
   $
For the second part, we use the formula for the sum of the first $n$ integers:
$
   \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i = \frac{(n-1) \times n}{2}
   $
Therefore:
$
   \sum_{i=1}^{35} \frac{i-1}{7} = \frac{1}{7} \sum_{i=0}^{34} i = \frac{1}{7} \times \frac{34 \times 35}{2} = \frac{1}{7} \times 595 = 85
   $

Combining the Results:
$
   E(\text{Total Rolls}) = 175 - 85 = 90
   $


This is also equal to $(min+max)/2$ assuming there is symmetry and therefore a normal distribution of # of roles in a game
